# Showing that losing positions in Wythoff's game are generated by $(\lfloor n\phi\rfloor, \lfloor n\phi^2\rfloor)$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory, pattern-recognition

A very neat problem in combinatorial game theory:

> In [Wythoff's Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wythoff%27s_game), how do I show that all the losing positions are generated by the formula
>
> $$\left(\lfloor n\phi\rfloor, \lfloor n\phi^2\rfloor\right)$$
> where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\phi$ is the golden ratio?
>
> More precisely, the $k^{\text{th}}$ losing position is $\left(\lfloor k\phi\rfloor, \lfloor k\phi^2\rfloor\right)$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

I have tried this problem for a while and got a way to show that the sequences $\lfloor n\phi\rfloor$ and $\lfloor n\phi^2\rfloor$ are disjoint and their union is $\mathbb{N}$, this can be easily showed using the Beatty's theorem, but I'm unsure how to prove that all the losing positions are generated by the formula $\left(\lfloor n\phi\rfloor, \lfloor n\phi^2\rfloor\right)$.

I have gone through wikipedia and its references for the proof, but it doesn't seem like the proof for the formula is present anywhere in the sources or references.

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The original paper [here](https://archive.org/details/nieuwarchiefvoo02genogoog/page/n219/mode/2up) has a proof, has it not? paragraph 6 mostly.

Comment: I went through it. It's a very pre-historic text and most terms from the book aren't very much legible. It would be very nice if you could just write the same proof in answer very briefly. I highly appreciate your time and efforts, Thanks.

Comment: Note that Wythoff uses $\lfloor k\phi \rfloor$ and $\lfloor k\phi  + k \rfloor = \lfloor k(\phi +1)\rfloor $ as the pair of losing positions. The $k$-th position should have difference $k$ and this is then made more clear. He uses $E\{.\}$ for the entier  function, as is common in those days. You're lucky the paper is in English (a lot of papers in that journal were in Dutch, German, or French; the default  foreign languages for Dutch scientists in 1907)..

Comment: Why is the difference $k$? The proof doesn't seem to be constructive, it doesn't prove that every losing position is $\left(\lfloor n\phi \rfloor, \lfloor n\phi^2 \rfloor\right)$. It would be great of you could elaborate more by answering the original question. I highly appreciate your time and efforts, Thanks.

Comment: The proof shows only that the two sequences ($x$ and $y$ coordinates) form Beatty sequences: they cover $\Bbb N$, which is one of the two conditions: the losing positions most contain all integers exactly once, and the difference between the $k$-th coordinate pair must be $k$. This also gives the quick algorithm for generating those positions. These conidions Wythoff remarks in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Why must the losing positions most contain all integers exactly once, and the difference between the $k$-th coordinate pair must be $k$? I'm not getting this part and how does it shows that $\textbf{every}$ losing position is is generated by the formula?

Comment: These properties are quite obvious if you reason about the losing positions (I only look above the diagonal). There are some youtube videos that give reasons in more extended form. Look for Wythoff there. NO times to write it down in detail. Essentially shows that the Beatty sequences for $(\alpha, \beta)$ only have the $k$-difference property iff $\alpha=\phi$ and $\beta=\phi^2$ (or vice versa), so that is the *unique* Beatty pair that works. He also gives other pairs that work but that do not have the difference property.

Comment: Alright, then how do I show that:  $a_n = \lfloor n\phi\rfloor$ and $b_n =  \lfloor n\phi^2\rfloor$ always have difference $k$? I got the part how to show that these 2 are Beatty sequences and cover $\mathbb{N}$ but how to show that these are unique?How? I highly appreciate your time and efforts, Thanks.

Comment: $n\phi^2= n(\phi+1)$ has difference $n$ with $n\phi$. Unicity is what Wythoff showed in the paper.

Comment: And why are the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wythoff’s argument is actually quite straightforward. He first identifies the $P$-positions (which he calls *safe* positions), i.e., the positions in which the previous player wins; equivalently, they are the positions in which the player whose turn it is to move must lose, assuming that the other player plays correctly. He lists the first few:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
u_n:&0&1&3&4&6&8&9&11&12&14&16\\
\ell_n:&0&2&5&7&10&13&15&18&20&23&26
\end{array}$$

(I’ve shortened his table a bit.) Clearly $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is a $P$-position: if you face this, the previous player has already won. The others in the table can be described as follows. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $U_n=\{u_k:0\le k<n\}$ and $L_n=\{\ell_k:0\le k<n\}$; then

$$u_n=\min\big(\Bbb Z^+\setminus(U_n\cup L_n)\big)\,,$$

and $\ell_n=u_n+n$.

Let $\mathscr{P}$ be the set of positions generated in this way. To show that $\mathscr{P}$ really is the set of $P$-positions, we need only show that every legal move from a position in $\mathscr{P}$ yields a position **not** in $\mathscr{P}$, while from every position not in $\mathscr{P}$ there is a legal move to a position in $\mathscr{P}$.

- Suppose first that $\langle u,\ell\rangle$ is a position not in $\mathscr{P}$ such that $u\le\ell$, and let $n=\ell-u$. If $u>u_n$, let $d=u-u_n$; taking $d$ from each pile leaves the position $\langle u_n,\ell_n\rangle\in\mathscr{P}$. If $u<u_n$, there is a $k<n$ such that $u\in\{u_k,\ell_k\}$. If $u=u_k$, removing $\ell-\ell_k$ counters from the larger pile leaves the position $\langle u_k,\ell_k\rangle\in\mathscr{P}$. If $u=\ell_k$, removing $\ell-u_k$ counters from the larger pile also leaves the position $\langle u_k,\ell_k\rangle\in\mathscr{P}$.
- Now let $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and consider moves from the position $\langle u_n,\ell_n\rangle$. If the result of such a move is in $\mathscr{P}$, it clearly must be $\langle u_k,\ell_k\rangle$ for some $k<n$. But then $$\begin{align*}\ell_n-\ell_k&=(u_n+n)-(u_k+k)\\&=(u_n-u_k)+(n-k)\\&>u_n-u_k\\&>0\,,\end{align*}$$ which is not possible with a legal move. Thus, there is no move from $\langle u_n,\ell_n\rangle$ to a position in $\mathscr{P}$.

This shows that $\mathscr{P}$ really is the set of $P$-positions. (Wythoff did not include the arguments given at the bullet points, merely noting that are easy.)

He then claims essentially that $u_n=\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor$ and $\ell_n=\left\lfloor n\varphi^2\right\rfloor$. Certainly

$$\begin{align*}
\left\lfloor n\varphi^2\right\rfloor-\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor&=\lfloor n(\varphi+1)\rfloor-\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor\\
&=\lfloor n\varphi+n\rfloor-\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor\\
&=\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor+n-\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor\\
&=n\\
&=\ell_n-u_n\,,
\end{align*}$$

and $\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor=\left\lfloor n\varphi^2\right\rfloor=0$ when $n=0$, so it only remains to show that when $n\ge 1$, $\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor$ is the smallest positive integer not equal to $\lfloor k\varphi\rfloor$ or $\left\lfloor k\varphi^2\right\rfloor$ for any $k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$. He does this by showing that $\langle n\varphi:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\left\langle n\varphi^2:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$ are complementary Beatty sequences, something that you’ve already done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it does really helps. But how did he get $u_n=\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor$ and $\ell_n=\left\lfloor n\varphi^2\right\rfloor$? What was the intution? how did he characterize the $P$-positions? I really appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks

Comment: @Permutator: I don’t know what his thought processes were, but I can see one possible way to arrive at the conjecture that $u_n=\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor$ and $\ell_n=\left\lfloor n\varphi^2\right\rfloor$. For $n=1,2,5,13$, i.e., the Fibonacci numbers $F_1,F_3,F_5,F_7$, we have $u_n=F_{n+1}$ and $\ell_n=F_{n+2}$, so that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ell_{F_{2n+1}}}{u_{F_{2n+1}}}=\varphi\,.$$ Moreover, direct computation suggests that $\ell_n/u_n$ is close to but a little bigger than $\varphi$ for all $n$. As for finding the $u_n$ and $\ell_n$ in the first place, I imagine that he probably ...

Comment: ... worked the first several out by hand and then spotted the pattern, as I’ve done with some other takeaway games. You’re welcome.

Comment: @Permutator: It’s [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio) that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\varphi$. (In fact, $F_n$ is always the integer closest to $\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}$.) As I noted, examining the early data suggests that if $n=F_{2k+1}$ for some $k$, then $u_n=F_{n+1}$ and $\ell_n=F_{n+2}$, so that $\frac{\ell_n}{u_n}=\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}$, which converges to $\varphi$ as $k\to\infty$. And actual calculation suggests that even when $n$ is not a Fibonacci number with an odd subscript, $\frac{\ell_n}{u_n}$ is always just ...

Comment: ... a bit bigger than $\varphi$.